# Wordpress - Make Gallery Posts from existing Photo Posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to start a photo blog on Wordpress. My Idea is to post raw pictures as posts. 1 pohoto per post. And then users can search for pictures (separate posts) and add them to galleries of their own, and then post those galleries.

Now, I can code this but first I thought to look up for something related, if available, then i'll code it if not found.

So, do you guys know any plugin which can do this or any alternative method for my plan?

thank

*** Update:
* The users will post the galleries in my site.
* What I have thought to do is to collect POST IDs of the images/posts which users select for a gallery and put it as an array in the new gallery post, so on POST show request, I'll just get the first image (attached image) from each of those IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done OOTB in WordPress, but something that isn't clear is - are the users posting galleries (a collection of posts) to your site to their profile? or their site?

Short simple answer to your question, plugins normally solves problems - your problem isn't clear. So no, I don't know of a plugin solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Of course, users will post the galleries to my site. Check my question for update info

Comment: You've answered your own question. There is no plugin, you would have to develop this yourself. I would like to see the site in use, and how users will be using it.